# How to match docker containers with directories under /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt?

Tags: docker

How can I determine which hash-named directory under `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt` corresponds to which running docker container?

("XY problem" questions hold-it-back request: I have done my homework, and this is **the** problem I need solved. Please don't ask what do I need this **for**. I need **this**, full stop. I am aware of several by-the-book means of accessing and modifying the contents of a running docker container, and please take my word that none of those other methods are suitable in the particular scenario involved).

Comment: Note that the devicemapper driver has been deprecated, and is going to be removed at some point: https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#device-mapper-storage-driver

Comment: When that day comes, I will probably have to install a text editor into every container.  In the rare case when a bug is completely non-reproducible outside the container running within the production infrastructure, the only way to debug without wasting cumulative hours on redeployment cycle is to edit code inside running container. Thanks for heads-up about the deprecation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who will need this (and for me in the future):

```
docker ps --format "{{.ID}}" | xargs docker inspect -f "{{.GraphDriver.Data.DeviceName}}    {{.Name}}"
```